# Why `void` is required while declaring a class template which is to be specialized using `enable_if`

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming, enable-if

I'm learning C++ template meta-programming and stumbled upon a simple SFINAE related (I believe so) issue. In particular, I'm writing a template class which will give us the type with largest size. I'm aliasing the `type` to be the right type depending upon their size by comparing types with `sizeof` operator. I'm selecting correct class specialization using `enable_if`. What I don't understand is why `void` needs to be provided as default value for `class Enable` while declaring a class template which is to be specialized using `enable_if`.

Following code works just fine

```
// test.cpp
#include <type_traits>

// void works just fine but if changed to anything else say int, compilation fails!
template < typename L, typename R, class Enable = void > struct MaxTypeT;

template < typename L, typename R >
struct MaxTypeT<L, R, typename std::enable_if< (sizeof(L) >= sizeof(R)) >::type> {
    using type = L;
};

template < typename L, typename R >
struct MaxTypeT<L, R, typename std::enable_if< (sizeof(L) < sizeof(R)) >::type> {
    using type = R;
};

int main(){
    static_assert(std::is_same< MaxTypeT<int, double>::type, double >::value, "MaxTypeT not working");
    return 0;
}
```

but when I change `class Enable = void` to any other type say `class Enable = int`, then I get following error. Why `void` is necessary here?

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:17:56: error: incomplete type ‘MaxTypeT<int, double>’ used in nested name specifier
     static_assert(std::is_same< MaxTypeT<int, double>::type, double >::value, "MaxTypeT not working");
                                                        ^~~~
test.cpp:17:56: error: incomplete type ‘MaxTypeT<int, double>’ used in nested name specifier
test.cpp:17:69: error: template argument 1 is invalid
     static_assert(std::is_same< MaxTypeT<int, double>::type, double >::value, "MaxTypeT not working");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::enable_if<>::type` is by default `void`. So your specializations each have a third parameter of `void` after template substitution occurs.

```
// primary template
template < typename L, typename R, typename Enable = void > struct MaxTypeT;

// specialization #1
template < typename L, typename R >
struct MaxTypeT<L, R, void> {
    using type = L;
};

// specialization #2
template < typename L, typename R >
struct MaxTypeT<L, R, void> {
    using type = R;
};
```

When you do `MaxTypeT<int, double>`, it instaniates the type `MaxTypeT<int, double, void>` because the default parameter `Enable` is set to `void`.

If `Enable` is set to `int`, it instaniates the type `MaxTypeT<int, double, int>`. Since the compiler can't match a specialization to those parameter types it goes with the primary template which has only been declared and not defined, hence the error.

As [Öö Tiib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60908971/701092) said in his answer `std::enable_if` has a second template parameter that specifies what its `::type` member will be. If you set it to `int` then it will be a specialization with the third parameter as `int` after sucessful template substitution.

Answer (score 2):

That `void` is not required it just saves you some typing. If you want to have `int` there then you should perhaps write it like that:

```
// test.cpp
#include <type_traits>

// int works just fine now
template < typename L, typename R, typename Enable = int > struct MaxTypeT;


// note additional template argument of enable_if
template < typename L, typename R >
struct MaxTypeT<L, R, typename std::enable_if< (sizeof(L) >= sizeof(R)), int >::type> {
    using type = L;
};

template < typename L, typename R >
struct MaxTypeT<L, R, typename std::enable_if< (sizeof(L) < sizeof(R)), int >::type> {
    using type = R;
};

int main(){
    static_assert(std::is_same< MaxTypeT<int, double>::type, double >::value, "MaxTypeT not working");
    return 0;
}
```

The second argument of `enable if` is `void` by default and so to match it your template has to have also `void` there or to provide different type to `enable_if`.